# What can a Rope of Climbing fasten to?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The [Rope of Climbing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/rope-of-climbing) description states:

> If you hold one end of the rope and use an action to speak the command word, the rope animates. As a bonus action, you can command the other end to move toward a destination you choose. [...] You can also tell the rope to fasten itself securely to an object or to unfasten itself, to knot or unknot itself, or to coil itself for carrying.

Other questions convey answers to [the motions capable by the rope](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/118729/what-are-the-motion-and-weight-capacities-of-a-rope-of-climbing-while-unattached) or whether the rope can [be commanded from either end](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120119/does-either-end-of-a-rope-of-climbing-fasten-on-command) but the objects to which it can attach seem unspecified which thus seems to suggest it is a DM's call.

Is there any precedent across published adventures or guidance expressed from game designers on the breadth of surfaces or objects to which the Rope of Climbing can attach? If so what?

For example, can it attach to a completely smooth surface?

Answer (score 10):

## It can fasten to anything a normal rope can

> You can also tell the rope to fasten itself securely to an object or to unfasten itself, to knot or unknot itself, or to coil itself for carrying.

The above passage does not grant the rope the supernatural ability to fasten to anything. Instead, it simply allows the rope to fasten itself to objects. Being that it does not get any more specific than that, it is fairly clear that this would mean any object a rope could be fastened to normally. If the object was granted the ability to attach to any possible surface it would say so, but it does not. Even though it is magically enhanced, it is still just a rope in the end.

If there is any question or disagreement about what a normal rope can fasten to, your DM will have to make the decision as to if the rope can attach to an object of your choice. If I were the DM I would not allow the rope to fasten to a completely smooth surface, because that is not something a normal rope can do.

Also, note that the rope specifically says that it fastens to objects. The definition of what counts as an object is left vague in the rules and is thus also in the realm of a DM to decide. Generally, walls are considered surfaces though and not objects. So a completely smooth surface would likely not qualify for fastening anyways.